# Ansible Roles and handlers - Cannot get role handlers to work

Tags: ansible

I need to set up Apache/mod_wsgi in Centos 6.5 so my main YAML file is as such:

```
---
- hosts: dev
  tasks:
    - name: Updates yum installed packages
      yum: name=* state=latest


- hosts: dev
  roles:
    - { role: apache }
```

This should update all yum-installed packages then execute the apache role.

The apache role is configured to install Apache/mod_wsgi, set Apache to start at boot time and restart it. The following are the contents of `roles/apache/tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
- name: Installs httpd and mod_wsgi
  yum: name={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - httpd
    - mod_wsgi
  notify:
    - enable httpd
    - restart httpd
```

And the handlers in `roles/apache/handlers/main.yml`:

```
---
- name: enable httpd
  service: name=httpd enabled=yes

- name: restart httpd
  service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

The handlers do not seem to run since the following output is given when I execute the playbook:

```
PLAY [dev] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [dev.example.com]

TASK: [Updates yum installed packages] **************************************** 
ok: [dev.example.com]

PLAY [dev] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [dev.example.com]

TASK: [apache | Installs httpd and mod_wsgi] ********************************** 
ok: [dev.example.com] => (item=httpd,mod_wsgi)

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
dev.example.com            : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And when I `vagrant ssh` into the virtual machine, `sudo service httpd status` shows `httpd` is stopped and `sudo chkconfig --list` shows it has not been enabled to be started by `init`.

I'm just starting out with Ansible, so is there something obvious I could be missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question, I realized that there's a subtle point I missed:

http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Specifically, the notify signal is produced only if the task introduces a change. So for my use case I think I'll go with enabling and starting Apache in standalone tasks instead of relying on change signal handlers.

Comment: Thanks for that! That's a distinction that's easy to miss when reading the docs.

Comment: Or, use handlers but add a `changed_when: true` element to the YUM stanza. This will have Ansible always consider the YUM to have "changed" things, which then will always notify the handlers to trigger, regardless of whether the packages were already installed or not.